# Remove items in array with quantity 0 in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I want to remove the items in array that has quantity of zero. i tried:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    serviceAvailed: [{"label": "Top", "quantity": 2}, {"label": "Bottoms", "quantity": 0}, 
    {"label": "Jacket", "quantity": 1}, {"label": "Beddings", "quantity": 0}, {"label": "Shoes", 
    "quantity": 0}];,
    }
```

On component did mount i looped the items inside the array and called the method removeItem that is supposed to remove all the items that has zero quantity

```
   componentDidMount() {
    let {serviceAvailed  } = this.state;
    serviceAvailed = this.state.array.map((item, i) => {
    let quantity=parseInt(item.quantity);
       if(quantity<1){
       this.removeItem(i)
       }});
   }
```

Function to remove the array

```
   removeItem(index) {
    const serviceAvailed = this.state.serviceAvailed;
    serviceAvailed.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ serviceAvailed });
    console.log(serviceAvailed)
   }
```

expected result:
serviceAvailed: [{"label": "Top", "quantity": 2}, {"label": "Jacket", "quantity": 1}];,

Comment: Why not simply use array.filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array filter method

```
let newArr = serviceAvailed.filter(function (e) {
        return e.quantity > 0;
    });
    console.log(newArr );
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

`array::map` is meant to map every element from an array to a new array. The operation is a ***one-to-one correspondence***. It's also meant to be a pure function, which means it has **ZERO** side effects, like removing elements of the array it is currently iterating over. `array::reduce` and `array::filter` are better options for removing elements, or otherwise "reducing" the input.

**Solution**

Using `array::filter` allows you to iterate over over an array and return a new array containing *only* elements that pass the filter predicate. Create a filter predicate function that returns true or false if an object's quantity property is greater than `0`.

```
const quantityGreaterThanZero = ({ quantity }) => quantity > 0;
```

Note: `0` is a "falsey" value, numbers greater than `0` are "truthy" values, so the above can be simplified to simply return the quantity. If it is truthy the predicate function is true, else it is false.

```
const quantityGreaterThanZero = ({ quantity }) => quantity;
```

Now you can pass your predicate function as the callback to `array::filter`.

```
const greaterThanZero = data.filter(quantityGreaterThanZero);
```

```js
const data = [
  { label: "Top", quantity: 2 },
  { label: "Bottoms", quantity: 0 },
  { label: "Jacket", quantity: 1 },
  { label: "Beddings", quantity: 0 },
  { label: "Shoes", quantity: 0 }
];

const quantityGreaterThanZero = ({ quantity }) => quantity;

console.log(data.filter(quantityGreaterThanZero));
```